# hierarchical navigation with conductor and event aggregator

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro, eventaggregator

This is my app architechture. Note that I have conductor as another conductor's child. And I have IHandle for each conductor to receive message from it's child.The message type is same as I use message just to navigating. My problem are I pass ShellView's EventAggregator to it's children.

How about NewConnectionView's EventAggregator ? Since I use it's EventAggregator for navigating on ShellView. And for it's children to navigating on it's ActiveItem.

How to separate these 2 EventAggregators in one ViewModel.

ShellView & NewConnectionView ==> Conductor.Collection.OneActive

```
                                         +----------------------------------+
                                         | ShellView                 |_|[]|x|
                                         +----------------------------------+
                                         | +------------------------------+ |
                                         | |                              | |
                                         | |                              | |
                                         | |                              | |
                                         | |         ActiveItem           | |
                                         | |                              | |
                                         | |                              | |
                                         | |                              | |
                                         | +------------------------------+ |
                                         +----------------------------------+
                                                     /       \
                                                    /         \
                                                   /           \
                                                  /             \
                                                 /               \
                                                /                 \
                                               /                   \
                     +----------------------------------+    +----------------------------------+
                     | NewConnectionView         |_|[]|x|    | ConnectionListView        |_|[]|x|
                     +----------------------------------+    +----------------------------------+
                     | +------------------------------+ |    | TextBlock                        |
                     | | ComboBox                 | V | |    | +----------------------+ +-----+ |
                     | +------------------------------+ |    | |                      | | Btn | |
                     | +------------------------------+ |    | |                      | +-----+ |
                     | |                              | |    | |                      | +-----+ |
                     | |                              | |    | |                      | | Btn | |
                     | |                              | |    | |    DataGrid          | +-----+ |
                     | |         ActiveItem           | |    | |                      | +-----+ |
                     | |                              | |    | |                      | | Btn | |
                     | |                              | |    | |                      | +-----+ |
                     | |                              | |    | |                      |         |
                     | +------------------------------+ |    | +----------------------+         |
                     +----------------------------------+    +----------------------------------+
                                 /       \
                                /         \
                               /           \
                              /             \
                             /               \
                            /                 \
                           /                   \
 +----------------------------------+    +----------------------------------+
 | FileConnectionView        |_|[]|x|    | DatabaseConnectionView    |_|[]|x|
 +----------------------------------+    +----------------------------------+
 |                                  |    |                                  |
 |                                  |    |                                  |
 |                                  |    |                                  |
 |                                  |    |                                  |
 |                                  |    |                                  |
 |                                  |    |                                  |
 |                                  |    |                                  |
 |                                  |    |                                  |
 |                                  |    |                                  |
 |                                  |    |                                  |
 |                                  |    |                                  |
 |                                  |    |                                  |
 +----------------------------------+    +----------------------------------+
```

Currently, my approach is using NewConnectionShellView (Screen) as NewConnectionView's (Conductor) parent to separate the EventAggregator. But the problem is, I can't get DisplayName of the NewConnectionView's children to display into my Main Window (ShellView).

Please note that I'm not using MEF. Is there any workaround for my problem ?

```
                                         +----------------------------------+
                                         | ShellView                 |_|[]|x|
                                         +----------------------------------+
                                         | +------------------------------+ |
                                         | |                              | |
                                         | |                              | |
                                         | |                              | |
                                         | |         ActiveItem           | |
                                         | |                              | |
                                         | |                              | |
                                         | |                              | |
                                         | +------------------------------+ |
                                         +----------------------------------+
                                                     /       \
                                                    /         \
                                                   /           \
                                                  /             \
                                                 /               \
                                                /                 \
                                               /                   \
                     +----------------------------------+       +----------------------------------+ 
                     | NewConnectionShellView    |_|[]|x|       | ConnectionListView        |_|[]|x| 
                     +----------------------------------+       +----------------------------------+ 
                     | +------------------------------+ |       | TextBlock                        | 
                     | |                              | |       | +----------------------+ +-----+ | 
                     | |                              | |       | |                      | | Btn | | 
                     | |                              | |       | |                      | +-----+ |
                     | |                              | |       | |                      | +-----+ | 
                     | |                              | |       | |                      | | Btn | | 
                     | |                              | |       | |    DataGrid          | +-----+ | 
                     | |         ActiveItem           | |       | |                      | +-----+ | 
                     | |                              | |       | |                      | | Btn | | 
                     | |                              | |       | |                      | +-----+ | 
                     | |                              | |       | |                      |         | 
                     | +------------------------------+ |       | +----------------------+         | 
                     +----------------------------------+       +----------------------------------+ 
                                    |
                                    |
                                    |
                                    |
                                    |
                                    |
                                    |
                                    |
                                    V
                     +----------------------------------+
                     | NewConnectionView         |_|[]|x|
                     +----------------------------------+
                     | +------------------------------+ |
                     | | ComboBox                 | V | |
                     | +------------------------------+ |
                     | +------------------------------+ |
                     | |                              | |
                     | |                              | |
                     | |                              | |
                     | |         ActiveItem           | |
                     | |                              | |
                     | |                              | |
                     | |                              | |
                     | +------------------------------+ |
                     +----------------------------------+
                                 /       \
                                /         \
                               /           \
                              /             \
                             /               \
                            /                 \
                           /                   \
 +----------------------------------+    +----------------------------------+
 | FileConnectionView        |_|[]|x|    | DatabaseConnectionView    |_|[]|x|
 +----------------------------------+    +----------------------------------+
 |                                  |    |                                  |
 |                                  |    |                                  |
 |                                  |    |                                  |
 |                                  |    |                                  |
 |                                  |    |                                  |
 |                                  |    |                                  |
 |                                  |    |                                  |
 |                                  |    |                                  |
 |                                  |    |                                  |
 |                                  |    |                                  |
 |                                  |    |                                  |
 |                                  |    |                                  |
 +----------------------------------+    +----------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to use one instance of the event aggregator for shell/plugin communication, and one instance per plugin for inter-view model communication. I would recommend using both an IoC container and register the shell event aggregator as a singleton, and then using factories which have a reference to the container to resolve instances of your view models.

You could have one message type which changes the display name and is published on the instance of the shell view event aggregator, and one message type which changes the current active item and is used on all event aggregator instances.

Comment: Using IoC means I use MEF too ?

Comment: Or ninject, autofac, etc.  MEF is a little different! The Dependancy Injection in .NET book does a good job of describing the differences.

Comment: Yes, there is nothing to stop you using MEF for your plugin architecture, and another IoC container for your general application infrastructure.